# Ignore pictures and files when loading a ResX

Tags: c#, resx

My web application reads a ResX resource file to load the localized strings. I'm not interested in images or in any other file the ResX may reference. However, if the ResX contains an image, for example, and the path to the image is not found on the machine, then an `ArgumentException` is thrown as soon as the `ResXResourceReader` is enumerated.

Is there a way to ignore all file paths and read all the other resources?

Comment: Why don't you store them in separate resource files?  Or better yet, don't store any images in the resource file if you're not interested in them.

Comment: @rory.ap That's what I usually did. However, now I have to load a resource file that comes from another project, by another developer. I'm keeping "asking him to split his resource files" as a last resource.